# Check if NSDecimalNumber is whole number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdecimalnumber

What's the easiest way to check if an instance of `NSDecimalNumber` is a whole number?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure. What about `if ([myDecNumber isEqualToNumber:[myDecNumber integerValue]])`?

Comment: Just cast your decimal value to int and check if its the same

Comment: Maybe something like this: `if ([myDecimalNumber decimalValue] / 1.0) > 0) {}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@interface NSDecimalNumber (IsIntegerNumber)
@property (readonly) BOOL isIntegerNumber;
@end

@implementation NSDecimalNumber (IsIntegerNumber)
-(BOOL)isIntegerNumber {
    NSDecimalValue value = [self decimalValue];
    if (NSDecimalIsNotANumber(&value)) return NO;
    NSDecimal rounded;
    NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &value, 0, NSRoundPlain);
    return NSDecimalCompare(&rounded, &value) == NSOrderedSame;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the whole number from the decimal number. If the difference is zero then the decimal number is a whole number.

```
// testVal is NSDecimalNumber
NSString *test = [testVal stringValue];
int intVal = [test intValue];
double doubleVal = [test doubleValue];
if(doubleVal-intVal == 0){
    NSLog(@"Whole number!");
}
```

Or, get the whole number and compare to the original value:

```
if(intVal == doubleVal){
    NSLog(@"Whole number!");
}
```

Comment: I submitted an edit of the answer and changed one 'double' to 'int'. However, I think that the origial version would work fine as well. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Any method that use `double` cannot be used with `NSDecimalNumber`. What if the number has 30 digits?

Comment: This is simpliest solution!

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

Beware of using methods that convert `NSDecimalNumber` into `double`.

```
NSDecimalNumber* input = [...];

NSDecimal roundedDecimal;
NSDecimalRound(&roundedDecimal, [input decimalValue], 0, NSRoundPlain);

NSDecimalNumber* roundedNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:roundedDecimal];

BOOL inputIsWholeNumber = [input isEqualToNumber:roundedNumber];
```

You should also check for `NaN` values.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test it out yet, but this seems to be the solution I'm looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: @James Also check out Jody Hagins' answer.

Comment: He/she submitted it right after accepted yours.  I upvoted both, but I think changing the accepted answer to his/hers may be more helpful to others looking for a quick answer.  Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use if ((number % 1) == 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation NSDecimalNumber (isWholeNumber)
-(BOOL)isWholeNumber
{
    double x = [self doubleValue]; //The approximate value of the receiver as a double.
    double y = floor (x);
    if(fabs(x - y) < DBL_EPSILON)
      return YES;
    return NO;
}
@end  
// [myDecNumber isWholeNumber];
```

Comment: You lose precision. `double` cannot cover all the values from `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: I was under the impression that a tiny bit of precision is lost when converting `NSDecimalNumber` to `double` or `float`.  I could be mistaken about this, but I'm curious to know if the outcome of this approach would be affected if that were indeed the case.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes because double is base-2 while NSDecimalNumber is base-10.

Comment: @James The loss caused by base-10 to base-2 conversion is significant but the important thing is that a `NSDecimalNumber` can hold up to 38 decimal digits while `double` ony about 16 decimal digits!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but for some reason I was unable to get Jody Hagins' or Sulthan's solutions to work so I went a slightly different way:

```
-(BOOL)isWholeNumber:(NSDecimalNumber *)number {
    NSDecimalNumber *input = number;

    NSDecimalNumberHandler *handler = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain
                                                                                             scale:0
                                                                                  raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                                                   raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                                                                  raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                                                               raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

    NSDecimalNumber *vOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1"];

    NSDecimalNumber *result = [number decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:vOne
                                                      withBehavior:handler];

    BOOL inputIsWholeNumber = [input isEqualToNumber:result];

    return inputIsWholeNumber;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this, you can skip first line, i just used it to create a NSDecimalNumber object

```
NSDecimalNumber  *decNumb=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"20.5"];//try with just 20
NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",decNumb];

if ([str rangeOfString:@"."].location==NSNotFound && [str rangeOfString:@"-"].location==NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"it is whole number");
} 
else
    NSLog(@"it is not whole number");
```

Comment: Not really good for localization. And what if the number is "2.0" ?

Comment: NSDecimalNumber automatically converts 20.0 to 20. Please check it your self

Comment: Can you check the above code by assigning 2.0 to decNumb. Somehow NSDecimalNumber seems to standardize 2.0 to 2.

Comment: Yes, it does that but it's undocumented behavior.