# Testing if a Decimal is an integer in Swift

Tags: swift, math

I'm doing some currency math and thus using the `Decimal` type. I want to test if a decimal number is an integer number (*i.e* a positive or negative whole number not the `Int` type). There's no modulus operator for `Decimal` in Swift, otherwise I'd just use that.

My understanding of decimal types is that they represent numbers as `integer * exponent`. Thus any integer number will have an exponent ≥ 0, and any number with a fraction component will have an exponent < 0.

Am I correct in my understanding, and this sample would be accurate?

```
if someDecimal.exponent >= 0 {
   print("Integer")
}
else {
   print("Fraction")
}
```

Comment: try this way `let isInteger = someDecimal.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) == 0`

Comment: @NazmulHasan he is using Decimal type

Comment: Well, it appears that non-canonical Decimals are possible -- I imagine that would be something like 100*10^(-1). I don't see a way to ensure that a Decimal is canonical. Maybe instead of looking at the exponent, you can inspect someDecimal._ulp and see if it >= 1 ?

Comment: @RobertDodier no need to use underscore

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks, autocomplete seemed to like _ better, but you're right.

Comment: @RobertDodier there is a `isCanonical` property, but [it's always true](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2e5817ebe15b8c2fc2459e08c1d462053cbb9a99/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Decimal.swift#L97). What does being canonical (or not) mean in the context of `Decimal`?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298755/check-if-nsdecimalnumber-is-whole-number are some solutions for NSDecimalNumber in Objective-C, they can easily be translated to Swift.

Comment: And here is the same question for Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033762/swift-decimal-iswholenumber.

Comment: Thanks all. Seems that the question Martin linked has the correct answer. I was close, but need to check that it is a normal number. Oddly that question didn't come up in Google or SO search for me.

Comment: You can have an integer decimal with a negative exponent (as @RobertDodier said), but you have to "hand-craft" such a number. I have added another answer to the duplicate which covers that case as well.